# How can I make circle GLSurfaceView on Videoview?

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-videoview, glsurfaceview

I'm using camera recorder library for video recording it's use GLSurfaceView. In my layout on VideoView I overlay GLSurfaceView.

**It's showing Circle shape when I overlay GLSurfaceView over ImageView**

**It's showing Square shape when I overlay GLSurfaceView over VideoView.**

I have tried below code for making circle GLSurfaceView.

> public class SampleGLView extends GLSurfaceView implements
>   View.OnTouchListener {
>
> ```
> private Path clippingPath;
>
> public SampleGLView(Context context) {
>     this(context, null);
> }
>
> public SampleGLView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
>     super(context, attrs);
>     setOnTouchListener(this);
> }
>
> private TouchListener touchListener;
>
> @Override
> public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
>     final int actionMasked = event.getActionMasked();
>     if (actionMasked != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
>         return false;
>     }
>
>     if (touchListener != null) {
>         touchListener.onTouch(event, v.getWidth(), v.getHeight());
>     }
>     return false;
> }
>
> public interface TouchListener {
>     void onTouch(MotionEvent event, int width, int height);
> }
>
> public void setTouchListener(TouchListener touchListener) {
>     this.touchListener = touchListener;
> }
>
> @Override
> protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
>     if (w != oldw || h != oldh) {
>         int radius = Math.min(w, h)/2;
>         clippingPath = new Path();
>         clippingPath.addCircle(w/2, h/2, radius, Path.Direction.CW);
>     }
> }
>
> @Override
> protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
>     int count = canvas.save();
>     canvas.clipPath(clippingPath);
>     super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
>     canvas.restoreToCount(count);
> } }
> ```

Is any one have idea how to solve it.

Comment: please check this blog may be its help you https://medium.com/remotepanda-blog/video-in-shapes-aa966e7d7be5

Comment: See [also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59658954/how-to-make-circular-mask-and-clip-glsurfaceview)